Receiving "The 'knowledge-article' tag is not allowed" error when editing Collective Article
I posted a draft for an Article in the CI/CD Collective "Articles" section.
See it at https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/articles/79297905/ci-cd-basics-and-definitions
Based on feedback, I tried to add a reply, but I am getting an inconsistent error message instead AND because of this, I cannot save the changes.
In the attached image, note the error message "The 'knowledge-article' tag is not allowed" and note that I do not have "knowledge-article" in the Tag section. That text is the radio button selected for Article type above the Tag list input box.
Apologies that the image is reversed, but I am doing reversed imaging at the Windows OS level, not with a Dark Mode in the Firefox browser. In any case, I don't see how that would affect this logic.


Articles internally use a tag to denote the article type which is why the tag is being added to it. See this answer. I don't know why that throws an error though, probably a bug.

@AbdulAzizBarkat : thanks for that feedback. I hope this gets picked up as a bug OR someone shows me the correct steps to edit my "Article" (-;.

@BenjaminW. : I tried to respond to your comments but as above, I couldn't get that to work. Maybe its me. I wanted to reply that as  I am completely unqualified to write about Ci/CD, I would leave my idea up for a while, and if there where no takers, either leave just the link to Wikipedia, or delete the article all together. When I saw you had written a response, I thought "Good, someone that knows what he's talking about" (-;! Cheers!
